# Using Maven for Ibm Web Experience Factory aka IBM WebSphere Portlet Factory Projects?

Tags: java, maven, websphere, portlet, websphere-portal

We are planning to use IBM Web Experience Factory for our future enhancements. From the project management point of view we are thinking of using Maven. But due to no online help available for using both the things together we are not able to move ahead.

Please let me know if anyone can provide inputs.

Answer (score 1):

We did a web application that needed to be deployed on IBM Websphere and we learned a couple of things. Maybe they can help you:

- If your application depends on certain IBM API's (like Virtual Member Manager), you should declare that dependency as provided and let the container manage it for you. For compilation purposes, you should add the required JARS to your Maven Repository (in our case, Archiva).
- For deployment you should relay on Jython scripts to do the Job. The execution of the scripts can be done with was6-maven-plugin (they say that they can handle the EAR deployment, but it can only be donde through Jython and wsadmin. Maybe you're more lucky than us)

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct maven integration for the IBM Web Experience factory.

Your best shot is using maven and ant. There are some guides on [build automation](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/pfwiki.nsf/dx/Automation_and_scripting_of_publishing_and_exporting_wpf701) in the [Web Experience Factory Wiki](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/pfwiki.nsf).

You have to do some [preparations](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/pfwiki.nsf/dx/Automating_the_generation_of_WAR_files_wpf701) and afterwards you [can generate the war](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/pfwiki.nsf/dx/Generating_a_WAR_file_using_the_command_line_wpf701).

You can integrate those tasks with [Maven AntRun](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).

We tried generating the war files with ant, however even though everthing compiled and the war looked good, we encountered problems within the application that stopped us continuing with this approach. It wasn't reliable enough.

Answer (score -2):

For the point Maven i don't understand how you get to say "no online help available" ...despite the official books http://sonatype.com/Support/Books you can read many things online on http://maven.apache.org/ furthermore there some other books which can be bought via Amazon or take a look at http://maven.apache.org/articles.html for an overview. Or for a starting point you can read at http://maven.apache.org/users/index.html. Last but not least you should take a look at the mailing lists for Maven. If you are searching for particular help about IBM WebSphere Portlet factory in relationship with Maven you should be more specific about the problem.